# JavaScript: How to sort data got from Firebase and show only part of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've tried create some function which could sort data from Firebase by highest score value and show only top 5. Now I can easily get and show on the web all data in appearing order, which is not very useful for me.

Function `gotData` give me proper format of data from Firebase and put every score in li element on the list.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(scores)) print 

{"-KYxmoU7NnbTk0EpURZO":{"initials":"Rafi","score":8},
"-KYxnLZ0HyftwOENmTs1":{"initials":"Wichru","score":13},
"-KYxndQcCmiRDet-kLlK":{"initials":"Meg","score":36},
"-KYxpnFkihQhung3_1s_":{"initials":"asas","score":0},
"-KZ0I4eeAvReZdlw-9dL":{"initials":"Ryan","score":28}}
```

I also did:

```
var values = Object.values(scores);
values.sort( (a, b) => b.score - a.score );
```

- as you said

and object is sorted by values of scores but still I can't print it on the web view

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('scores');
console.log(ref);
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

function gotData(data) {
    var scorelistings = document.querySelectorAll('.scorelisting');

    for (var i = 0; i < scorelistings.length; i++){
        scorelistings[i].remove();
    }

    var scores = data.val();
    var keys = Object.keys(scores);
    var olList = document.getElementById('list');

    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var k = keys[i];
        var initials = scores[k].initials;
        var score = scores[k].score;

        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.classList.add('scorelisting');


        $(olList).append(li);
        var scoreArr = $('ol').find('li');
        var count = $("ol").find("li").length;

        li.innerText = initials + ": " + score;
     }
}

function errData(err) {
    console.log('error');
}

function submitScore(e) {
    var data = {
        initials: nickname.value,
        score: score
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    // console.log(data);
    ref.push(data);
    scoreBoard.style.display = "none";
    highscoreBoard.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Did you try limitToFirst()? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#limitToFirst

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the data by creating a new array based on the scores object, which contains the objects within *scores*. So the *key* is replaced by a sequential (array) index (the *key* is added to a copy of each object so you still have it). Then sorting that array is simple. And you can use `.every()` to stop iterating once you have 5 results:

```
var scores = data.val();
Object.keys(data.val())
    .map ( key => Object.assign({ key }, scores[key]) )
    .sort( (a, b) => b.score - a.score )
    .every( (score, rank) => {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.classList.add('scorelisting');
        li.textContent = score.initials + ": " + score.score;
        $(olList).append(li);
        return rank < 4;
    });
```

Comment: Massive! Thank you for quick response!